# Granite ORM + fiber + mysql = Unexpected EOF (Exception)?

Tags: crystal-lang, amber-framework

Is working with Fibers in Granite possible?  I didn't have a reason to believe otherwise, until I attempted to write some code for it.  I am attempting to learn to work with Fibers, so perhaps incorrect fiber implementation could also be a cause.  The following code results in an  exception.  Any hints to resolve this?

```
  lines = File.read_lines INVENTORY_FILE
  channel = Channel(Int32).new(199)
  lines[0..200].each do |line|
    row_number += 1
    proc = ->(line : NamedTuple(item_number: String) do
      spawn do
        sku = Sku.find_by :item_number, item_number
        channel.send(1)
      end
    end
    proc.call({ line: line })
  end

  199.times do |i|
    channel.receive
  end
```

The above results in the following repeated exception starting from the very first fiber's attempt to access the DB.  I've ensured that MySQL is in a working state and that the code works when fibers are not in use:

```
Unexpected EOF (Exception)
    from lib/mysql/src/mysql/read_packet.cr:38:18 in 'read_byte!'
    from lib/mysql/src/mysql/read_packet.cr:63:5 in 'read_int'
    from lib/mysql/src/mysql/packets.cr:13:7 in 'read'
    from lib/mysql/src/mysql/connection.cr:63:14 in 'read_packet'
    from lib/mysql/src/mysql/connection.cr:22:19 in 'initialize'
    from lib/mysql/src/mysql/connection.cr:4:3 in 'new'
    from lib/mysql/src/mysql/driver.cr:3:5 in 'build_connection'
    from lib/db/src/db/pool.cr:255:3 in 'build_resource'
    from lib/db/src/db/pool.cr:34:22 in 'checkout'
    from lib/db/src/db/pool.cr:65:7 in 'checkout_some'
    from lib/db/src/db/database.cr:99:7 in 'checkout_some'
    from lib/db/src/db/pool_prepared_statement.cr:35:24 in 'build_statement'
    from lib/db/src/db/pool_prepared_statement.cr:53:22 in 'initialize'
    from lib/db/src/db/pool_prepared_statement.cr:11:5 in 'new'
    from lib/db/src/db/database.cr:89:7 in 'build_prepared_statement'
    from lib/db/src/db/database.cr:7:15 in 'fetch_or_build_prepared_statement'
    from lib/db/src/db/session_methods.cr:23:9 in 'build'
    from lib/db/src/db/query_methods.cr:38:7 in 'query'
    from lib/granite/src/granite/querying.cr:53:12 in 'find_by'
    from /usr/share/crystal/src/kernel.cr:0:3 in '~procProc(Nil)'
    from /usr/share/crystal/src/fiber.cr:255:3 in 'run'
    from /usr/share/crystal/src/concurrent.cr:0:3 in '~proc2Proc(Fiber, (IO::FileDescriptor | Nil))'
    from ???
```

Comment: Does this work without `spawn` ?

Comment: Maybe related to https://github.com/amberframework/granite/pull/220

Comment: @FaustinoAguilar yes, this works without spawn.  Ok, I'll get the latest granite code to see if the pull did the trick; however, from a rough overview of the pull request, it seems to be a different issue.  Will update if the above fixed it.

Comment: Can you try isolating this? The EOF error seems more like it has to do with `File.read_lines`
Does the code work without issue if you remove everything that granite is doing? And just `channel.send(1)` in the fiber?